# How to save a new workbook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Why i am getting this error while adding a newworkbook and saving in the path

```
Workbooks.Add.SaveAs "C:\Users\TAPAN BEHERA\OneDrive\Documents\Vlookupdata.xlsm", 52
```

Error I am getting is -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5EE8.png)

Comment: Do you call this from within Excel?

Comment: Please post fuller code and not line snippets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.